# Exclude a file in terraform module source

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to exclude a `.tf` file when specifying the source in a module.

**Example**

`foo/bar` consists of multiple `.tf` files:

- file1.tf
- file2.tf
- file3.tf

Is it possible to exclude `file1.tf` while including it `foo/bar` in source as below:

```
module "module1" {
  source = "foo/bar"
  version = "0.1.0"
}
```

Comment: No but you could set the count of the resources to 0 I guess? Or you could have nested modules where you have a child module and a parent module where sometimes you just directly call the child module and ignore the extra stuff in the parent module. Do you have a more specific example?

Comment: Rename the file: change `.tf` to anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't supported explicitly. [You can use some of the workarounds detailed in this Medium post](https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9), like setting the `count` of a resource equal to a variable that you've set to boolean `true` or `false`:

file1.tf:

```
resource "aws_eip" "example" {
  count = "${var.create_eip}"
  ...
}
```

dependent source:

```
module "module1" {
  source = "foo/bar"
  version = "0.1.0"
  create_eip = false  # set to 'true' to include the resource in file1.tf
}
```