# Does Terraform support ignoring a file?

Tags: terraform

Is there anything like `.gitignore` or `.dockerignore` in Terraform to ignore a `.tf` file?
Or is some workaround to stop rendering a specific `.tf` file?

Comment: You could just rename the file to `whatever.tf.notused` or something like that. By default, terraform will look at all the files with `.tf` extension. Or you might as well remove the file.

Comment: I'd really commend reading this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13021#issuecomment-473680222 If that doesn't help, you should describe Why you want to ignore specific files, as there may be alternative patterns. Without knowing the Why, this risks being an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: So there is no any `.terraformignore` or .`tfignore`? right? @MarkoE

Comment: Correct, such a `.ignore` does not exist in terraform. Which is already discussed on SO here : [Exclude a file in terraform module source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447912/exclude-a-file-in-terraform-module-source)